# trying to test latency connection between 2 virtual server

Tags: testing, networking, server, virtual, latency

by using Netperf tools on Microsoft azure cloud, on client i use :netperf -H ip-server  -l 1800 -P 10 -t TCP_RR -- -o min_latency,mean_latency,max_latency,stddev_latency,transaction_rate

0n server : netserver -p 50000

getting error on client as :recv_response_timed_n: no response received. errno 4 counter 0

note : both server are same configuration

Comment: What are ports for client and server?

Comment: port number is 50000

Comment: in client command how that port is mentioned? I do not see -p, does it run on 50000 by default?

Comment: yes usually by default

Comment: in case I  add port number in client command line its give me that sentence :  establish control: are you sure there is a netserver listening on 20.151.132.18 at port 50000?
establish_control could not establish the control connection from 0.0.0.0 port 0 address family AF_UNSPEC to 20.151.132.18 port 50000 address family AF_INET

Answer (score 0):

"recv_response_timed_n: no response received. errno 4 counter 0" implies the remote netserver died for some reason.  Or at least that has been my experience over the years.  From that message alone it isn't clear if that is waiting on the initial test response from netserver or waiting on test results from netserver.  The former would happen much sooner than the 1800 second test runtime your client command line seems to be requesting.

It isn't clear what you are trying to do with "-P 10" as that option, when used in the "global" command-line space, really just takes 0 or 1 as a value to control whether the test banner/headers are displayed. "10" will have the same effect as "1" here.

As already pointed-out, port 50000 is not the "default" control connection port number for netperf.  That would be 12865.  When you run:

netserver -p 50000

you might also run netstat -an to make certain netserver is indeed listening on port 50000 rather than its default port.

Also, the netserver will allocate a second port number for the data connection.  That will be based on whatever the stack running on the netserver system chooses.  Your firewall rules (I assume there are some on Azure) will need to account for that.  If you want to pick a specific port number rather than open all TCP ports between your two VMs, you would then use a test-specific -P option to specify that port number on the netperf command line.  Netperf will then communicate that to netserver which will set-up the data connection to use that port number.

The "are you sure" message suggests there was not something actually listening at the port number specified for the control connection.  Or, if the firewall "actively" rejects connections, that the firewall did so.